# DB2 moving data from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, db2

I try to moving data from windows db to linux by ibm data studio. After all operation i see success result, numbers of moved rows, and numbers of commited rows.
[image]
But when i select rows from db on linux, it's return null.

Comment: Possible reasons include, different database, or different table, or different schema, or rows got deleted after insertion, or table got dropped and recreated. Do some eliminations and you will find the mistake.

Comment: We need a reproducible test case to help you (using code). Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.